# Should we curate answers on closed questions on small sites?

Tags: discussion, answers, closed-questions

Sometimes on small sites (<5k questions) I come across a bad answer on a closed question.  I'm not talking about answers that are merely wrong, for which the right tools are downvotes and comments; I'm talking about answers that are flag-worthy (e.g. NAA) or in need of major edits.

1. As a user, should I treat this answer the same way I would if the question were open, because the content is still available on the site even if the question is closed?  Or should I assume that the question being closed will be enough of a signal to readers who come across the page, and I should just ignore it and move on?
2. As a moderator, how (if at all) should I factor in the question's status (open, on hold, closed) when handling a flag on such an answer?

This question is specifically about small sites.  I understand that a different approach might apply on sites with tens (or hundreds) of thousands of questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is there a chance of reopening the question, or is the question closed as a duplicate?

If so, treat answers to it like you would treat answers to an open question. Edit for clarity or to correct minor mistakes, delete non-answers, etc. Treat closed questions as lower priority if you're looking for stuff to do, but if you've decided a particular post requires attention, go for it.

If the question isn't going to be reopened and isn't a duplicate, delete the question.

Whether you're a moderator or not doesn't change what should be done, only the tools at your disposal (e.g. flagging to delete vs. deleting).

Comment: I guess it largely comes down to - Is there much of a difference between deleting an answer, or just deleting the attached question? (i.t.o how the posted of the answer is affected) There isn't as far as I know, unless we're talking about spam / offensive.

Comment: Sometimes a closed question still has useful answers, particularly if it's closed because of scope drift (it was once on-topic but isn't now).  Other times the whole question should just be flushed.